# Digital multimeter product on the Internet and Integration of Camera electronics

Tags: hardware, communication, data-transfer, interoperability, interfacing

[Digital multimeter](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/learn/blog/electrical/what-is-a-digital-multimeter)

Will it be useful to have camera electronics integration in Digital multimeter product as well as have DMM product on the Internet or "WWW"?

Comment: You have a tendency to ask such weird and broad questions, which are clearly off topic here…

Comment: useful to whom?

Comment: you can simply purchase a DMM that contains a LAN interface and judge for yourself if a network connected DMM is useful